# UDP Packets coming in with wrong formatting

Tags: c++, networking, udp, posix, sfml

I'm currently working to get some software that is currently running on windows ported over to ubuntu. One aspect of this software handles udp packets with the location of some of our assets using SFML. For some reason after moving OS's the packets are coming in as U� (always with the � symbol.) is this a posix problem? Here is the code I was using:

```
int32_t
SocketUdpClient::recv(std::string *data)
{
   sf::Socket::Status recvStatus = sf::Socket::Error;
   
   if( m_bOpen && data != NULL )
   {
      char          buf[4096];
      std::size_t   bytesRead;
      sf::IpAddress senderIp;
      uint16_t      senderPort;

      recvStatus = m_socket.receive( buf, 4096, bytesRead, senderIp, senderPort );

      if (recvStatus == sf::Socket::Done)
      {
        std::cout << "Received " << bytesRead << " bytes from " << senderIp << " on port " << senderPort << std::endl;
        std::cout << buf <<std::endl;
          m_senderIp = senderIp.toString();
          if (m_listenAll) 
          { 
              m_peerIp = senderIp.toString();
              
              printf("SocketUdpClient::recvfrom m_senderIp = %s, m_peerIp = %s\n", m_senderIp.c_str(), m_peerIp.c_str());
          }

          if (m_senderIp.compare(m_peerIp) == 0)
          {
              *data = std::string(buf, bytesRead);
              return bytesRead;
              //return senderIp.toString();
          }
      }
      else if (recvStatus == sf::Socket::NotReady) 
      {
          return 0;
      }
   }
   
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: *the packets are coming in as U�* is unclear. Is this coming out of one of the diagnostic prints, the contents of the packet, or what?

Comment: Also, please post the code to `m_socket.receive` - that appear to be your local socket class. If there is a bug, it's more likely to be in that function.

Comment: As others have said, it's not quite clear what you mean. For instance that ? mark symbol may just be an encoding issue (like some windows code-page to an ubuntu utf8 terminal)  in whatever is displaying the printing, and may not be an issue with the socket code at all.

When asking questions it's often helpful to *start* with the literal error you see, screenshot if necessary, and what system you see it on, *then* show the code.  This is close, just wasn't specific enough.

Comment: So the packets coming in as U� is referring to what is printed by std::cout << buf <<std::endl;

Comment: the code to m_socket.recieve is part of the sfml UDPSocket class: https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1UdpSocket.php

Comment: The error im getting is coming from this code in the class that parses the incoming packets. `action error {
      if (m_verbose) printf("error on %02x\n", fc);
      badMessageSignal();
      m_nBadMessages++;
      clear();
      fhold; fgoto consume;
   }`

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
  recvStatus = m_socket.receive( buf, 4096, bytesRead, senderIp, senderPort );

  if (recvStatus == sf::Socket::Done)
  {
    std::cout << "Received " << bytesRead << " bytes from " << senderIp << " on port " << senderPort << std::endl;
    std::cout << buf <<std::endl;
```

To this:

```
  bytesRead = 0; // always a good idea
  recvStatus = m_socket.receive( buf, 4095 /* 1 less than buffer size*/, bytesRead, senderIp, senderPort );

  if (recvStatus == sf::Socket::Done)
  {
    std::cout << "Received " << bytesRead << " bytes from " << senderIp << " on port " << senderPort << std::endl;

    buf[bytesRead] = '\0';  // null terminate
    std::cout << buf <<std::endl;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt change anything.